# Rename a sheet with TextBox value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a Form, and I wnat to rename the sheet. Actually, program does it correctly, but when I want to use .Activate function I get an error : Type mismatch

```
Worksheets.Add().name = UserForm1.txtNameSur

Worksheets(UserForm1.txtNameSur).Activate
```

I've also tried

```
Worksheets("&UserForm1.txtNameSur&").Activate
```

Still the same.

Thanks!

Comment: what is the value of UserForm1.txtNameSur?  Is it a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GD Stefan,

The .Activate method of Worksheets is expecting either an index (integer or long) or a string, identifying the page to activate. You are passing an object in the form of an TextBox to the .Activate method. Try passing the value, rather than the whole object, as VBA gets confused as to what to do with that TextBox where it is expecting only a String or an Integer or Long variable.

i.e.:

```
Worksheets.Add().Name = UserForm1.txtNameSur.Value
Worksheets(UserForm1.txtNameSur.Value).Activate
```

That should work !